# Passing POST data from ionic framework to CodeIgniter Rest API

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, ionic-framework, codeigniter-3

From last two days i'm try to post the data from my Ionic app to CodeIgniter rest api using $http. But my post data goes empty. I refere some link. But failed to seolve. Below is my code.

My ionic view

```
 <div class="list">
       <label class="item item-input item-md-label" placeholder="Username" highlight-color="balanced" type="text">
              <input class="md-input" type="text" ng-model="user.name">
              <span class="input-label">Username</span>
              <div class="hightlight hightlight-calm"></div>
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input item-md-label" placeholder="Password" highlight-color="energized" type="password">
              <input class="md-input" type="password" ng-model="user.password">
              <span class="input-label">Password</span>
              <div class="hightlight hightlight-calm"></div>
            </label>

        </div>
        <div class="padding">
            <button ng-click="doLogin(user)" class="button button-full button-assertive ink">Login</button>
        </div>
```

Ionic Controller code :

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk, $http, baseUrl) {
    $scope.$parent.clearFabs();
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
    }, 0);
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();

  $scope.doLogin = function(user) {

    $http({
      method : "POST",
      url : "http://localhost/vas_api/index.php/api/User/index/"+user.name
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {      
      console.log(response)
    });
  }    
})
```

CodeIgniter controller code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

class User extends REST_Controller {

    public function index_post() {
      if(!$this->input->post('name')) {
        $this->response(null, 400);
      }

      $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name')
      );

      $id = $this->User_model->insertUser($this->input->post('name'));

      if(!is_null($id)) {
        $this->response(array('response' => $id), 200);
      }  else {
        $this->response(array('response', 'Null values'), 400);
      }
    }   
}
```

Codeigniter model code :

```
<?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model { 

  function insertUser($data) {
    $this->db->insert('user',array('name' => $data));
    $userId = $this->db->insert_id();

    return $userId;
  }

}

?>
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I'm using advance CodeIgniter version 3 Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using post but not posting any data to post data use `,data:{name:user.name}`

Comment: $http({
      method : "POST",
      url : "http://localhost/vas_api/index.php/api/User/index/",data:{name:user.name}
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {      
      console.log(response)
    }); I need to use like above format, correct?

Comment: @Sathosh please have a look at my answer below also let me know if it is not working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following approach

```
$http({
      method : "POST",
      url : "http://localhost/vas_api/index.php/api/User/index/",
      data:{ name:user.name }
    }).then(function(response) {      
      console.log(response)
    });
```